# How to get the filenames with the extension os .xsd from the Project

Tags: c#

I am having a project which is named as myfirstproject.In that I am having .cs files .xsd files .rpt files and .config files etc.Here I need to get the filename of .xsd files,if it is example.xsd,I need to get the example file name in one datatable.Like that all the .xsd file names should be filled in one datatable.The project exists in any C or D or E drive in that drive myfirstproject is the solution name and project name.In that I need to get the filenames with the extensions of .xsd.I am working with windows application.Please help me with suggestions or solution
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You do realize that unless you *copy* those to the *output* folder, they will not be available at runtime right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this helps:

```
var root =  new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)).Parent.Parent;
var allXsdFiles = root.EnumerateFiles(".xsd", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
DataTable tblFiles = new DataTable();
tblFiles.Columns.Add("Filename");
tblFiles.Columns.Add("Directory");
foreach (FileInfo xsd in allXsdFiles)
    tblFiles.Rows.Add(xsd.Name, xsd.Directory);
```

Maybe you need to to play around with the root folder. I have used `Application.ExecutablePath` to get the bin folder. Normally your project path is two parents above.

Comment: EnumerateFiles is not coming in intellisense,I need to add any namespace

Comment: @user2897388: if you're not using .NET4 you can use `GetFiles`

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve files from disk by using many different methods. The System.IO namespace contains many helper classes that are useful to you.

Usually you wouldn't want to read directly from your solution directory (you will read files from the executable directory, relative to the executable directory, or from a directory configured in your configuration file. Many of the methods also depend on whether you're using winforms or webforms.

The following bit of code is not something I would use in a production system, but will scan through the executable directory and pick up every .xsd file and writes it to the console, for a winforms application:

```
foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Application.ExecutablePath, "*.xsd")) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Webforms / MVC would require you to swap out Application.ExecutablePath for something else.

Also, you will need to set all .xsd files to "Copy to output directory" in their VS settings.

Comment: The directory name is invalid.I am getting error.The path is  E:\myfirstproject\myfirstproject\bin\Debug\myfirstproject.EXE

Comment: Sorry - use System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "*.xsd"))